# (TypeError: Bird() takes no arguments.)

Tags: python, pygame

Hi guy I am still pretty new at python and I decided to take on this project called [( "Python Flappy Bird AI Tutorial(with NEAT) - Moving Birds](https://youtu.be/ps55secj7iU), I know ima get some SH*# for taking on a more advanced project but can I get some help, kind of committed now Thank You!. I am using Visual Studio Code , with python 3.7.7, pygame 1.9.6.

```
import neat
import pygame
import time
import os
import random

WIN_WIDTH = 600
WIN_HEIGHT = 800


BIRD_IMGS = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(
    pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png"))), pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))
PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(
    pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "pipe.png")))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(
    pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "base.png")))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(
    pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bg.png")))


class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def _init_(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]

    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1

        d = self.vel * self.tick_count + 1.5 * self.tick_count**2

        if d >= 16:
            d = 16

        if d < 0:
            d -= 2

        self.y = self.y + d

        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL

    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1

        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME * 2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME * 3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME * 4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME * 4 + 1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME * 2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(
            center=self.img.get_rect(topLeft=(self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topLeft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)


def draw_window(win, bird):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0, 0))
    bird.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    bird = Bird(200,200)

    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
        draw_window(win, bird)
    pygame.quit
    quit()


main()
```

and this the error I get on my terminal.

> Hello from the pygame community.
>   https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "/Users/EGC/Desktop/Python Tutorial/flappyBird.py", line
>   110, in 
>       main()   File "/Users/EGC/Desktop/Python Tutorial/flappyBird.py", line 98, in main
>       bird = Bird(200,200) TypeError: Bird() takes no arguments

and these are the problems
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w4VJ.png)

Comment: Typo: `_init_` should be `__init__`

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` requires *double* underscores (you have single underscores).

I.e. change `_init_` to `__init__`